# Xlrd very slow opening excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an excel file, I guess it is quite huge for an excel file (200Mb), it has around 20 sheets full of information.

My question is that if it is normal that the following simple action takes almost 5 mins to execute. I am wondering if I am doing it in the correct way.

```
import xlrd

def processExcel(excelFile):
    excelData = xlrd.open_workbook(excelFile)
    sheets = excelData.sheet_names()
    print sheets
```

As you can see, on the first step I am just trying to get the sheet names and only that simple thing takes 5 mins...is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible. That is indeed a lot of data to be in an Excel file. By default, `xlrd` loads the entire workbook into memory. If your workbook is a .xls file, you can use the `on_demand` parameter to only open worksheets as they are needed:

```
import xlrd

def processExcel(excelFile):
    excelData = xlrd.open_workbook(excelFile, on_demand=True)
    sheets = excelData.sheet_names()
    print sheets
```

If you are trying to open a .xlsx file, the `on_demand` parameter has no effect.

***Update***

If you are using Python 3 and reading a .xlsx file, you can try [**sxl**](https://pypi.org/project/sxl/). This is a library which only reads things into memory as needed. So just opening the workbook to retrieve the worksheet names is very quick. Also, if you just need the first few rows of a worksheet, it can get those rather quickly as well.

If you need to read all the data with `sxl`, you have to iterate over all the rows, which could be even slower than `xlrd`, but at least will only use up as much memory as you need. For example, the following code will only keep one row in memory at any given time:

```
from sxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook('MyBigFile.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets[1]
for row in ws.rows:
    print(row)
```

However, if you need random access to all the rows to do your processing, you'll have to keep them all in memory:

```
from sxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook('MyBigFile.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets[1]
all_rows = list(ws.rows)
```

In this case, `all_rows` keeps the entire sheet in memory. If your workbook has multiple sheets, this may still be more efficient than `xlrd`. But if you need your whole workbook in memory, then you might as well stick to `xlrd`.

Comment: I don't have much experience using [OpenPyXL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) but its [read-only mode](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html) is supposed to help with very large files. It's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks! Pls add `excelData.release_resources()` otherwise file remains open. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241837/python-xlrd-book-how-to-close-the-files

Comment: Can you please provide an example for retrieving sheet names?