# Python xlrd.Book: how to close the files?

Tags: python, file-io, xlrd

I read 150 excel files in a loop, opening them with `xlrd.open_workbook()`, which returns a `Book` object. At the end, when I tried to `umount` the volume, I was unable, and when I checked with `lsof`, I found that 6 of the files were still open:

```
$ lsof | grep volumename

python2   32349         deeenes  mem       REG               0,40    138240     181517 /.../150119.xls
python2   32349         deeenes  mem       REG               0,40    135168     181482 /.../150609.xls
python2   32349         deeenes  mem       REG               0,40    140800     181495 /.../140828.xls
python2   32349         deeenes    5r      REG               0,40    140800     181495 /.../140828.xls
python2   32349         deeenes    6r      REG               0,40    135168     181482 /.../150609.xls
python2   32349         deeenes    7r      REG               0,40    138240     181517 /.../150119.xls
```

Here is my function I read the xls files with:
*(stripped for clarity)*

```
import sys
import xlrd
from xlrd.biffh import XLRDError

def read_xls(xls_file, sheet = '', return_table = True):
    try:
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_file, on_demand = True)
        try:
            sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet)
        except XLRDError:
            sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        table = [[str(c.value) for c in sheet.row(i)] for i in xrange(sheet.nrows)]
        if not return_table:
            table = None
        return table
    except IOError:
        sys.stdout.write('No such file: %s\n' % xls_file)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The `Book` object does not have `close()` method, neither have any open file type objects among its properties, except the stdout. This [howto](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Book-class) does not tell about this (haven't found the official docs). I don't see how I could close the file, and also it is weird that 6 remains open after reading 150 of them.

*Edit:* it might be related to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/general.html#loading-worksheets-on-demand), but still should not leave open files, and I don't want to read all sheets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to close a workbook using xlrd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403781/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-workbook-using-xlrd)

Comment: Thanks Reto, it's a shame I haven't seen this among the suggestions. More exactly, in one comment `release_resources()` mentioned, that should help me.

Comment: I checked, it works. In case of using `on_demand = True` at opening, one need to call `book.release_resources()` on closing. This can be found only in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403781/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-workbook-using-xlrd#comment10131975_5403934

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In case you open a workbook with `on_demand = True` for a more economic resource use ([see here how does it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250416/854988)), you need to call `release_resources()` method at the end. As a minimal example:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('workbook.xls', on_demand = True)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[str(c.value) for c in sheet.row(i)] for i in xrange(sheet.nrows)]
book.release_resources()
del book
```